# What is this kind of coding style in c?

Tags: c, coding-style

```
(void) fputs( line, stdout );
(void) alarm( TIMEOUT );
```

The above appears in the function body,I've never seen such code before...

Comment: What do you mean? The `(void)` part?

Comment: Yes,when is that useful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a form of *coding to debugging tools* at the expense of human beings reading your code, and it's *Considered Harmful*. In particular, the classic `lint` tool and perhaps some compilers generated warnings if you did not use the return value of a function that returned a value, and the only way to suppress this locally was to cast the result to `void`.

Either ignore it, or fix it (remove the useless `void` casts) if you have sufficient authority to do so.

Comment: I've always read the `(void)` to mean "I know this returns a value but I've explicitly decided I don't need it".  For instance `alarm()` returns the time left to any previously set alarm which you probably don't really care about. Prefixing it with `(void)` says I've considered that `alarm()` returns a value, but I don't want it.  Similarly for `fputs()` but `fputs()` can fail so with `fputs()` you would be saying "I'm going to ignore the errors" which is obviously bad.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say at least half the time you do not need the return values of library functions, and ignoring them does not mean ignoring errors. For instance with `fputs`, you can much more easily just check `ferror` at the end of the whole write operation rather than constantly checking the return value of `fputs`, yielding code that's much simpler (and therefore less likely to contain bugs). I see no reason you should make explicit the fact that you're not using the return value. The simple fact that you're not using it is apparent from reading the code.

Comment: @JeremyP: What R. is saying is that generally this is for the benefit of tools rather to a person reading the code. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Non_002dbugs.html for a rationale why GCC won't be making it the default to warn if return values are ignored: "Warning about this practice only leads the defensive programmer to clutter programs with dozens of casts to void. Such casts are required so frequently that they become visual noise. Writing those casts becomes so automatic that they no longer convey useful information about the intentions of the programmer".

Comment: By the way, checking for error return from individual output functions in `stdio` is generally meaningless, since you won't encounter the error until much later when the buffer is full and the flush fails. With this in mind, simply checking `ferror` at the end makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing unusual are the casts to `void`. It's a way to indicate that you're going to ignore the return value of the function, or to indicate that a function returns no value.  Some compilers warn about ignored return values, so can be a way around that warning. I don't think it's very good style myself.

Comment: Isn't it the same if `void` not there?

Comment: Yes, it's just a cast to `void`, and yes, the code has exactly the same meaning without the cast. Some compilers or tools may issue a warning without the cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `(void)` part, then that is explicitly discarding the result of the function call.  `fputs(...)` returns an `int`. `(void) fputs(...)` discards the `int` return value without generating compiler warnings.